# Unable to add multiple entities in ManyToOne mapping due to Unique Key being created

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have been fighting this issue regarding two entities: User and ProfileInformation.

**Each user should hold many ProfileInformation instances** but I  get the following error when creating a second ProfileInformation: `Duplicate entry 'usernameInQuestion' for key 'UK_141232asdas78k552'`.

When checking the database schema for **ProfileInformation** I noticed that the '**username**' field was created as a unique key:

```
 `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_14113pekuxo8jklda2678k552` (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKt3ewldgdc9d75ji6j5ii7cbrc` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`)
```

I have a very similar relation between ProfileInformation and another entity with the same code (except the naming of the classes and     `@JoinColumn(name = "profileinformation_id")` ) and this doesn't happen:

```
`profileinformation_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKl5ww2gn1e1wgqcuvraa6p70ya` (`profileinformation_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKl5ww2gn1e1wgqcuvraa6p70ya` FOREIGN KEY (`profileinformation_id`) REFERENCES `profileinformationtable` (`id`)
```

This is part of a bigger system and between all the confusion of making this work I attempted to replicate the already working similar situations.

```
public class ProfileInformation

[ ... ]

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private User user;
```

The User class is the following (although from what I gather this really doesn't seem to matter much):

```
public class User

[ ... ]

@Id
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
private String username;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ProfileInformation> infos;
```

Comment: We are using MySql 5.7 in this system

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?